# Зацикленное перекрытие блоков по z-index - как решить?

Tags: html, css, css3, bootstrap

Есть верхнее меню `nav`, чекбокс, раскрывающий дополнительное меню и кнопка спозиционированная в правом верхнем углу при ховере на которую выпадает еще одно меню. Столкнулся с очень удивительной для себя проблемой перекрытия `z-index`.

В текущем положении при нажатии на чекбокс и вызове доп меню не могу нажать белый крестик справа из-за перекрытия ховером кнопки в углу справа.

Если увеличиваю `.navbar-expand-lg { z-index: 99999; }`, то теперь доп меню закрыть могу, но выпадающее меню теперь недоступно.

По сути палка о двух концах. Можно ли решить эту задачку без перестановок `html` ?

[Код в фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/mq63vb7a/)

```css
.navbar-expand-lg {
  z-index: 9999;
}

.navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav {
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 145px;
  align-items: center;
}

nav#expand-fullpagemenu {
  /* Full screen nav menu */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgba(4, 25, 51, 0.95);
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999999;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: auto;
  -moz-transition: visibility 0s 0.5s, opacity 0.5s, -moz-transform 0.5s;
  /* transition settings */
  -webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0.5s, opacity 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: visibility 0s 0.5s, opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
}

input[type="checkbox"]#togglebox:checked~nav#expand-fullpagemenu {
  /* nav state when corresponding checkbox is checked */
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  -transition-delay: 0s;
}

nav#expand-fullpagemenu label#closex {
  /* Large x close button inside nav */
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: -1000px;
  z-index: 99999999;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
}

nav#expand-fullpagemenu label#closex::before,
nav label#closex::after {
  /* render large cross inside close button */
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -3px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

nav#expand-fullpagemenu label#closex::after {
  /* render large cross inside close button */
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

nav#expand-fullpagemenu a {
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Circe-ExtraBold";
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 4.2px;
}

nav#expand-fullpagemenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  /* center UL vertically inside nav */
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateY(-50%);
  /* center UL vertically inside nav */
  transform: translateZ(0) translateY(-50%);
  font: bold 2em 'Bitter', sans-serif;
  /* use google font inside nav UL */
}

nav#expand-fullpagemenu ul li {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

nav#expand-fullpagemenu ul li a:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 145px;
  height: 145px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.button:hover+.inner {
  display: block;
}

.inner {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 21px 46px;
  top: 144px;
  width: 489px;
  max-width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li>Меню 1</li>
    <li>Меню 2</li>
    <li>Меню 3</li>
  </ul>
  <input type="checkbox" id="togglebox">
  <label for="togglebox" id="navtoggler"></label>
  <nav id="expand-fullpagemenu">
    <label for="togglebox" id="closex">Close</label>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ссылка 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ссылка 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</nav>
<div class="button"></div>
<div class="inner">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: смотрите, как реализовано здесь - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/916526/265406

Comment: @UModeL спасибо большое за направление на интересное решение, но в данном случае не знаю как применить это в моем примере

Comment: Как насчет использовать JS?

Comment: @E_K я не против, но как вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: @Вася, отследить изменение `input` и добавить класс к кнопке с меньшим `z-index` или сразу уменьшать его.

Comment: @E_K все равно не понимаю - про какой `input` идет речь? Все равно любой элемент входящий в `nav` выше его по `z-index` не станет